# Python randomized program not working out

Tags: python, if-statement, random, fall-through

I made a basic randomized program on my Raspberry Pi, and it goes somewhat like this.

```
import random
print ("Welcome to the PC Expo's new game, PC Dispenser, what will you win?")
WinorLose = random.randint(1, 1000)
if WinorLose <100:
    print ("You won a Nintendo Wii.")
elif WinorLose >200:
    print ("You won a Sony PSP.")
elif WinorLose > 300:
    print ("You won a Nintendo Wii U.")
elif WinorLose > 400:
    print ("You won a Sony PS Vita.")
else:
    print ("Not your lucky day, Try again.")

print ("Thank you for the visit.")
```

if you cannot tell what it does, it has a chance of giving you a virtual PSP, Wii U, and so on. But all it is doing is printing rather "You win a Sony PSP", or "Not your lucky day, Try again." What is wrong? Any fixes?

Answer (score 6):

Put the largest number first:

```
WinorLose = random.randint(1, 1000)
print(WinorLose)
if WinorLose > 400:
    print ("You won a Sony PS Vita.")
elif WinorLose > 300:
    print ("You won a Nintendo Wii U.")
elif WinorLose > 200:
    print ("You won a Sony PSP.")
elif WinorLose < 100:
    print ("You won a Nintendo Wii.")   
else:
    print ("Not your lucky day, Try again.")
```

if `WinorLose` is `> 400` then it is also `> 100` so you would always print the first statement.

You might also want to use an upper and lower bound:

```
if 400 <= WinorLose < 500:
    print ("You won a Sony PS Vita.")
elif 300 <= WinorLose < 400:
    print("You won a Nintendo Wii U.")
elif 200 <= WinorLose < 300:
    print ("You won a Sony PSP.")
elif  WinorLose < 200:
    print ("You won a Nintendo Wii.")    
else:
    print ("Not your lucky day, Try again.")
```

Using `if 400 <= WinorLose < 500` etc.. would work in any order as we are setting a range with a lower and upper bound so unless `WinorLose` is in that range the statement would not evaluate to True.

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an answer above but I guess it didn't explain why yours didn't work, so I'll point it out to you so you can avoid it next time.

Lets consider where the problem occurs.

`elif WinorLose > 200:`

This will be true for any numbers greater than 200 so 201..1000 in your case; therefore the if statement has been completed because a condition has been met. This will also be the same for other conditions that followed in your code.

Hope this explains why yours didn't work as expected.